# Создание пустого файла txt в приложении Андроид

Tags: java, android

Я в тупике, не могу сообразить код java для создания пустого файла txt во внутренней памяти телефона в директории

> Имя пакета/files/

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать, перебрал кучу примеров, ни один толком не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал все проще. В связи с тем, что система создает файл в указанной директории, писать код с указанием папки нет необходимости.
А файл я создал так:

```
FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                fos = openFileOutput("note" + ".txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
```

Все работает именно так, как мне и требовалась

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте данный код, завалялся в старых проектах:

```
// ИМПОРТЫ
import java.io.File;

// КОД
// Путь к папке files внутри внутренней памяти приложения
        String filePath = context.getFilesDir().getPath() + File.separator + "MyFile.txt";
        
File file = new File(filePath);
        
try {
// Создание файла, если его не существует
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
        // код после создания
    } else {
        // код при существовании
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.i("INF", "Ошибка при создании файла: " + e.getMessage());
}
```